# I have stored procedure created in the database, in my C# code I want to convert the insert query into that stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

Please find the C# code where right now I'm inserting as a normal query, but I have created a stored procedure for insert which takes 7 parameters

```
try
{
    string query = @"insert into dbo.PhotoContest values('" +
                        photo.contestTitle + @"' , '" +
                        photo.contestLocation + @"' , '" +
                        photo.contestDescription + @"' , '" +
                        photo.votingType + @"' , '" +
                        photo.voteDate + @"' , '" +
                        photo.voteEndDate + @"' , '" +
                        photo.partDate + @"' , '" +
                        photo.partEndDate + @"' , '" +
                        photo.uploads + @"' , '" +
                        photo.photoOption + @"' , '" +
                        photo.caption + @"')";

    // method to execute the query
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PhotoContestDB"].ConnectionString))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
    using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        da.Fill(table);
    }

    return "Added successfully!";
}
```

And this is my stored procedure which I created in my database:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dbo.InsertPhotoContest;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertPhotoContest
    (@PhotoContestID int OUTPUT,
     @contestTitle varchar(500),
     @contestLocation varchar(500),
     @contestDescription varchar(500),
     @votingType varchar(255),
     @voteDate datetime,
     @voteEndDate datetime,
     @partDate datetime,
     @partEndDate datetime,
     @uploads varchar(500),
     @photoOption varchar(500),
     @caption varchar(500))
AS
BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO dbo.PhotoContest (contestTitle, contestLocation, contestDescription, 
                                  votingType, voteDate, voteEndDate, 
                                  partDate, partEndDate, uploads, photoOption, caption)
    VALUES (@contestTitle, @contestLocation, @contestDescription, 
            @votingType, @voteDate, @voteEndDate,
            @partDate, @partEndDate, @uploads, @photoOption, @caption);

    SELECT @PhotoContestID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.PhotoContest 
    WHERE PhotoContestID = @PhotoContestID;
END;
```

I just need to know how to convert my query into stored procedure. As you can see in my code 11 parameters which I need to insert. In my photo contest table, there is `photoContestID` which is identity (which means it auto increments), first is my stored procedure correct, also wanted to know how would I use my stored procedure in my C# backend code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this - and I would not really return the whole inserted row from the stored procedure (since you've already passed in all the input parameter values anyway) - just read the return new ID value from your `OUTPUT` parameter.

```
// set up your connection and command
using (var con = new SqlConnection(.....))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.InsertPhotoContest", con))
{
    // define it as stored procedure
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    
    // add input parameters and set their value
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@contestTitle", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = photo.contestTitle;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@contestLocation", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = photo.contestLocation;
    // and so forth, for all 11 input parameters
    
    // separate output parameter
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PhotoContestID", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    
    // open connection, execute stored procedure, close connection
    con.Open();
    
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // get newly assigned ID        
    int newPhotoContestID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@PhotoContestID"].Value);
    
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: will not work. SP + ExecuteNonQuery returns `-1` "For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1."

Comment: I think, OP wants not the count but the ID. In this case he can even do `OUTPUT INSERTED` etc

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the answer , it worked , that @PhotoContestID int OUTPUT in my SP , i have used that because when i insert this entry , at the same time , considering the PhotoContestID , i want to insert the data in another table.

Comment: Also , why SP  + ExecuteNonQuery returns -1 ? and why it won't work ?

Comment: @Rajesh: absolutely nothing wrong with using the `@PhotoContestID int OUTPUT` at all ! Glad this works for you now

Comment: @marc_s , Another doubt .
I  wanted to know , using this insert ( Considering PhotoContestID as Identity ( 1,1 ) )
I am trying to insert the data in another table using PhotoContestID as Primary Key. 
How would i do it in stored procedure ?

Comment: @Rajesh: if you have another question - please ask this as a separate question on SO and describe what it is you're trying to accomplish or what you're unsure about

Comment: @marc_s when i add 
 // separate output parameter
```    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PhotoContestID", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
```
along with 
```
int newPhotoContestID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@PhotoContestID"].Value);
```

Im getting error saying too many parameters

Comment: @Rajesh: since I don't see your code, I cannot tell you much - except for: check your parameters - make sure, you specify all of them, but each only once, and no extra parameter..... compare the parameters of the stored procedure to the list of parameters in your C# code.

Comment: @marc_s , found the error thanks it was duplicate entry , 
But when i insert data from my front end application , there are 2 inserts happening in my procedure ? how is it happening ?

Comment: @Rajesh: is there a **trigger** on that table?

Comment: @marc_s no there are no trigger on that table.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is this

```cs
DataTable table = new DataTable();

using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PhotoContestDB"].ConnectionString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.InsertPhotoContest", con)) // SP NAME
using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
    
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; // CHANGE THIS
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("contestTitle", . . . . )); 
    // ADD MORE PARAMETERS HERE

    con.Open();
    da.Fill(table);
} // this will dispose all objects and close conn inside dispose
```

In your SP you don't need parameter `@PhotoContestID int OUTPUT,` because you are returning the entire row and you can do `int id = (int)table.Rows[0]["YOUR-COLUMN-NAME"];`

You could also invest into how to use `OUTPUT INSERTED` with your `INSERT` and SP return value

Comment: `string query = "dbo.InsertPhotoContest"`  For CommandType.StoredProcedure the CommandText should be just the name of the stored procedure.

Comment: @marc_s `ExecuteNonQuery` returns `-1` when SP executed. OP retrieves the inserted record

Comment: Why ExecuteNonQuery returns -1 ?

Comment: @Rajesh while you at it. Make a simple stored proc with only `INSERT` in it. Perform `ExecuteNonQuery` from code and retrieve return value. `var i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery`. And tell me here, is this `1` or `-1`